# What does 対向拠点 mean?

Tags: meaning

Full text: VPNにおける対向拠点は最大1000対地.

My understanding: VPNにおける = "At VPN"
最大1000対地 = "Maximum 1000 tunnels/zones"

My Issue: 対向拠点. Does it mean some counter for positions or is it opposite bases?

Comment: BTW please keep in mind that you are supposed to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/719822) to indicate your problem has been resolved.

Comment: @naruto Sure I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter? 拠点 can work as a counter (e.g., 15拠点 = fifteen bases/locations), and so is 対向拠点, but obviously it's not used as a counter here.

I'm not an expert of this field but this 対向(拠点) seems to refer to a "peer" (i.e., another similar machine located at the other side of the network). From what I googled, "opposite base" is not an established term in the field of networking.

Comment: 対向拠点 = endpoint. This is basically a VPN endpoint. I searched quite a bit and found the answer. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @HarpreetSinghKapula Okay, "endpoint" seems reasonable too.